# BASH/SED: Match a line, then repeat that line n times immediately after match

Tags: bash, sed

Let's say I have a file called `template.inp` containing the following:

```
filename
clustername
>>>>
repeatline 0. 0. 0. z. z. z.
>>>>
do_something.sh
>>>>
```

And I want to match on `repeatline` and then copy that whole line `$repeatnum` times, such that `template.inp` looks like for `repeatnum=2`:

```
filename
clustername
>>>>
repeatline 0. 0. 0. z. z. z.
repeatline 0. 0. 0. z. z. z.
repeatline 0. 0. 0. z. z. z.
>>>>
do_something.sh
>>>>
```

Not sure how to do this elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's easy to do repeat a line a variable number of times in `sed`. But you can do it with a simple shell loop.

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    if [[ "$line" == repeatline* ]]
        for ((i=0; i<repeatnum; i++)) do
            echo "$line"
        done ;;
    fi
done < template.inp > template.outp
mv template.outp template.inp
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to match on `repeatline`:

```
awk "-vrepeatnum=$repeatnum" '
/^repeatline[[:space:]]/  { for(i=0;i<repeatnum;++i) print }
                          { print }
' template.inp
```

- First `/` - start of regex pattern matching
- `^` - start of line anchor
- `repeatline` - literal match on `repeatline`
- `[[:space:]]` - match on any whitespace character
- Second `/` - end of regex matching pattern

Comment: Alternatively, `$1 == "repeatline"` might be a little more readable.

Comment: @glennjackman Absolutely! That'd be a reasonable replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try:

```
repeatnum=2                             # bash variable
awk -v rep=$repeatnum '                 # pass it as an awk variable
/^repeatline/ {                         # if matched
    for (i = 1; i <= rep; i++) print    # then repeat the line
}
1' template.inp                         # "1" to print any lines
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need loops ***at all*** to repeat lines in `awk` :

```
echo 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 9' | 
gawk '(OFS = RS $(NF = (__ = $NF)^_))^!(NF = __)'  # repeat count in $2
```

---

```
echo 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' | 
mawk '(OFS = RS $_)^!(NF = __)' FS='\n' __=9       # repeat count as parameter
```

---

```
 1  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 2  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 3  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 4  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 5  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 6  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 7  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 8  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 9  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
repeat_count=2
sed -E '/^repeat/{:a;x;s/^/n/;/^n{'$repeat_count'}$/{x;b};x;p;ba}' file
```

Use the hold space as a counter.

N.B. The last print of the repeated line is done by the sed cycle.

Another way is to use the unix philosophy of small compositional programs:

```
seq $repeat_count | sed 's/.*/p/' | sed -e '/^repeat/{' -f - -e 'd}' file
```

And another way:

```
printf "%0.sp\n" $(seq $repeat_count) | sed -e '/^repeat/{' -f - -e 'd}' file
```